# After using models.Model on my class Im getting 'ImproperlyConfigured' error Django

Tags: python, django, module, settings

I just started a new project in django, I run the command 'django-admin startproject + project_name', and 'python manage.py startapp + app_name'. Created a project and app.

I also added my new app to the settings:
[settings pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMIpy.png)

After that I tried to create my first module on 'modules.py' file on my app, but when I do it and run the file, it gives me this error message:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX3n1.png)
The entire error message says:
" django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings. "

I created a few projects before, and never had this problem.

I discovered that if I dont use the 'models.Model' on my class, it does not gives me this error.
[No error message on this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Dg2.png)

Someone knows what it is about, and why it gives me this error? I didnt change anything on settings, just added the app.

Comment: To run Django one should use `python manage.py runserver` from the project directory. You should not directly run `models.py` like you do. Also after adding / changing any model you should first run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: So its normal to get this error, when we run models.py file?

I also did the changes to the database with 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' but the error is still there after I run the models.py file.

Answer (score 0):

You must add your `apps.py` in your `settings.py`.

"app1", added in the list as you did can't work. You should add the app to your INSTALLED_APPS using <name_directory_containing_your_app>.<your_app_name>.apps.<name_of_the_class_in_apps.py>.

Mine looks like this for example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apps.core.apps.CoreConfig'
```

]

Where 1th apps is the name of the directory containing my app, "core" is the name of the app, apps is the apps.py module & CoreConfig is the name of the class in apps.py.

Comment: I search the 'DJANGO_APPS = [] ' on my settings file but there is no field with this name. I only have the field 'INSTALLED_APPS =[]' which was created automatically by django when I created the project.
 Can you please specify were did you find this 'DJANGO_APPS' field on your settings.py file?

Comment: @khavro Sorry, i just modified my settings making a custom configuration.
Your list name is "INSTALLED_APPS=[]" and not "DJANGO_APPS=[]", there you should do what i've said above. Let me know

Comment: I made this change to my INSTALLED_APPS,  and the result is the same, the error still appears. 
On previous projects I just added the name of the app, like on the screenshot, and it worked. That´s weird.

Comment: the name of the app you should add in INSTALLED_APPS is the path of the class in the apps.py of that app. And the path changes based on BASE_DIR. 

It means you added the wrong path.

To make it work, you should have this within your INSTALLED_APPS:
`app1.apps.app1Config'

Comment: @khavro I guess now it works! thanks for your vote!

Answer (score 0):

After a long research I figured out that this is a normal message that should appear to everyone who tries to run the 'modules.py' file instead of running the project itself.

You dont need to do anything with this error, it will not affect your project and it's not telling you that something is not working.
It's just telling that you should run the project and not the 'modules.py' file.